# Formula for CDF of investment returns

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, finance

How can I calculate a cumulative density function or probability density function for investment returns based on expected return of a stock and volatility of a stock?

My current solution is below, but I am looking for feedback on whether it is correct or not, or solutions using alternative assumptions.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Options-Futures-Other-Derivatives-6th/dp/0131499084

Comment: Found it on p275. Thank you. Looks like I mixed up SD and variance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming returns are normally distributed, the probability of returns is given by:
$$
    \text{Lognormal}((\mu-\sigma^2/2)T,\ \sigma\sqrt{T})
$$

Where $\mu$ is the expected return of the stock and $\sigma$ is the volatility of the stock.

Comment: “Probability of returns” is a bit vague and it is not entirely clear what the notation below it means. Likely, you are using that to represent the CDF $F_T(x)=\mathbb{P}(X_T\leq x)$ which is the probability of the log-return $X_T$ *being less than* $x$ at time $T$, when $X_T$ is a simple Itô diffusion with adjusted drift (i.e. is normal with mean and standard deviation just as you specify). Returns are not log-normal by the way—prices are since $S_t=S_0e^{X_t}$ with $X_t=(\mu-0.5\sigma^2)t +\sigma B_t$ where $B_t$ is a Brownian motion.